# google map identify an address in Paris

Tags: google-maps, dictionary

I need to identify if an address in paris is *left or right side* of "la Seine" (the river in Paris" it is to calculate a fare for taxi on an internet site with WP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - nice to have you. Please read How do I ask  a good question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example to help keeping Stack Overflows content on the highest possible level and increase your chances getting an appropriate answer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: WP? WordPress? You didn't ask a question and have expended no effort. https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you may to give 2 coordenates the left side of "la seine" and the right side. Evalute if the current coordenate is highter or iqual from the right side. The current position is in the right side!

Example: 48.8526691,2.3522807 is the coordenate the right side.

if(current_coodenate > 2.3522807){return 'It's in right side'}

Comment: thank's is it efficient for any adrress in paris , because la seine is note a 
straight line

Comment: not as simple :

48.854099, 2.334725 left side and  48°51'36.2"N 2°20'03.3"E right side

Comment: You're using the wrong coordinates. You should to use latitude and longitude coordinates that provide google maps.

Answer (score 0):

using postal codes is the right way to identify left or right sides

leftSide = [75005, 75006, 75007, 75013, 75014, 75015]

others are in the right side